# How to correctly implement a table view with a fixed number of custom cells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a `UITableView` I need to have just 3 cells. This is what I have in IB: [image: IB table view and cells]. All cells contain a `UITextField`, and that's why are using custom cells. Each cell is binded to a `CustomCell` class with the corresponding `UITextField` as an outlet. I also have protocols to pass the texts in the `UItexField` to the table's `UIViewController`.

In the `UIViewController` I have this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = UITableViewCell()

    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "firstNameCell", for: indexPath)
        (cell as! FirstNameTableViewCell).delegate = self
    case 1:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "lastNameCell", for: indexPath)
        (cell as! LastNameTableViewCell).delegate = self
    case 2:
        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "birthdateCell", for: indexPath)
        (cell as! BirthdateTableViewCell).delegate = self
    default:
        break
    }

    return cell
}
```

But here:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
tableView.register(FirstNameTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "firstNameCell")
tableView.register(LastNameTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "lastNameCell")
tableView.register(BirthdateTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "birthdateCell")
}
```

The contents of the cells are not shown.

Which is the correct way to deal with this scenario?

Comment: If you have fixed cells why dont you create a static cells in UITableViewController in storyboard itself and can directly draw the IBOutlets from textFields to your VC. As cells are not getting reused xCode won't complain and it makes sense as well from logical point of view :) The  hassle to create delegates are unnecessary for a fixed number of cells :)

Comment: Side-note, not related: You **never** have to register cells if they are designed in Interface Builder.

Comment: @vadian you mean storyboard, right?

Comment: @SunilChauhan Yes, I mean storyboard but also if `Main` is a xib.

Comment: @vadian Just curious: when we don't need to register custom cells when using xib?

Comment: @SunilChauhan If you do everything in code or if you load external cells via xibs.

Answer (score 0):

As Sandeep Bhandari said, if you want to keep static cells, then use static cells in tableview:

[image: UITableView with static cells]

You can specify number of rows, sections, and number of rows in each sections etc. there in storyboard itself.